# rspec execute command on failure

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

Given I have a test like

`expect(['x', 'y', 'z']).to be_empty`

How can I get execute a command when the test fails, for example, to put the contents of my failed test into a csv file with row names specific to the data in that test.

The best way I can think of to do this is

```
begin
  expect(['x', 'y', 'z']).to be_empty
rescue RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError => e
  #output to csv
  raise e
end
```

However this doesn't feel like the cleanest way to do it.

Another option would be to put this in on failure hook in cucumber, however I would lose my ability to specify row names, or would need to define row names beforehand, which also feels weird.

Is there any cleaner, more precise way to go about this?

**Note: These tests are being run with cucumber**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`after`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) hook to check the example status.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example#exception-instance_method

```
after do |example|
  if example.exception.nil?
    # passed
  else
    # failed
  end
end
```

Comment: While not exactly what i'm looking for, this seems to be the best way to do what I want without catching the exception

Comment: ^Great answer, shorthand: `after { |example| e = example.exception; binding.break unless e.nil? }`

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted to be able to do that as well! So I wrote a gem that lets you define an `on_failure` handler to output any information that would be helpful for debugging (or execute any Ruby code that you want).

With [`rspec-on_failure`](https://github.com/TylerRick/rspec-on_failure), you can write your example either like this:

```rb
on_failure ->{ output_to_csv } do
  expect(['x', 'y', 'z']).to be_empty
end
```

or this:

```rb
on_failure ->{ output_to_csv }
expect(['x', 'y', 'z']).to be_empty
```